# How to remove all timers

Tags: sdk, timer, delay, coronasdk

How can I remove all `timer`s that I lunched with `timer.performWithDelay`?

what I've tried:

```
for id in pairs(timer) do
    print("timer: " .. id)
    if id ~= nil then
        timer.cancel( id )
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the timer table private variables:

```
for id, value in pairs(timer._runlist) do
     timer.cancel(value)
end
```

Otherwise the best 'legit' method is to store your timer ids in your own table for example like that:
Adding a timer:

```
aTimers = {}
aTimers[0] = timer.performWithDelay( 1000, yourFunction, 0 )
```

Canceling a timer:

```
timer.cancel(aTimers[0])
```